# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body user_id: Value "info" is not snowflake

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making a discord bot and one of the commands is a kick command, so the problem is when you input "=kick info" its supposed to display an embed that will give you information about the command and it keeps giving me the error

`DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body user_id: Value "info" is not snowflake.`

It used to work just fine, but for some reason it started to give me this error, not only with this command but with all the others as well.

I tried to make a separate command that would display the embed if you typed =info "command" but that didn't work, if there is a fix for this please do let me know.

Here is the code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: 'Use this command to kick a member from the server so that they have to recieve an invite to re-join it.',
    async execute(client, message, args) {
           let PermissionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setDescription(":no_entry: **You do not have Permission to use this command.**")
           .setColor('#FF0000');
   
           let PermissionEmbed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setDescription(":no_entry: **I do not have Permission to Kick members.**")
           .setColor('#FF0000');
           
   if(!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send(PermissionEmbed);
   if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send(PermissionEmbed2);

   let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
   const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]);
   let yes = 'info'
   let ErrorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription(":no_entry: **User could not be kicked, the user's role is higher than mine**")
   .setColor('#FF0000');

   let ErrorEmbed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription(":no_entry: **User could not be kicked, the user's role is higher than Yours**")
   .setColor('#FF0000');

   let ErrorEmbed3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription(":no_entry: **You cannot kick me.**")
   .setColor('#FF0000');

   let ErrorEmbed4 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription(":no_entry: **You cannot kick yourself.**")
   .setColor('#FF0000');

   const KickedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setDescription(':white_check_mark: **Successfully Kicked '+mentionedMember.user.tag+'**')
   .setColor('2eb82e')

   const Embedhelp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Kick Command')
   .setColor('#6DCE75')
   .setDescription('**Description**\nUse this command to kick a member from the server so that they have to recieve an invite to re-join it')
   .addFields(
     { name: '**Usage:**', value: '=kick (user) (reason)'},
     { name: '**Example:**', value: '=kick @Michael gtfo'},
     { name: '**Info**', value: 'I cannot kick members that have a higher role than me\nYou cannot kick members that have a higher role than you.\nYou cannot kick me.\nYou cannot kick yourself'}
  )
   .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());

   if (!reason) reason = 'No reason given';
   if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (args[0] === yes.toLowerCase)
   if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (!mentionedMember.kickable) return message.channel.send(ErrorEmbed);
   if (mentionedMember.user.id == message.author.id) return message.channel.send(ErrorEmbed4);
   if (mentionedMember.user.id == client.user.id) return message.channel.send(ErrorEmbed3);
   if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= mentionedMember.roles.highest.position) return message.channel.send(ErrorEmbed2)

   const kickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle('You have been Kicked from '+message.guild.name)
     .setDescription('Reason for Kick: '+reason)
     .setColor('#6DCE75')
     .setTimestamp()
     .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());

    await mentionedMember.send(kickEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
    await mentionedMember.kick({
      days: 7,
      reason: reason
    }).catch(err => console.log(err)).then(() => message.channel.send(KickedEmbed));
    }
}
```

I tried searching online for a fix but couldn't find any that worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your message content is `=kick info`, `args[0]` is the string `"info"`. When you try to fetch the member using `message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])` it sends a request where the `user_id` is `"info"` which is not a valid [snowflake](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#snowflakes).

A quick fix would be to check the value of `args[0]` earlier and return if it's `"info"`:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'kick',
  description:
    'Use this command to kick a member from the server so that they have to recieve an invite to re-join it.',
  async execute(client, message, args) {
    if (args[0] === 'info')
      return message.channel.send('Some info about this command...')

    let PermissionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    // ...
```

Comment: I tried the fix that @Zsolt Meszaros told me to try but it did not work, it still gives me the same error